# Keep svg pattern scaling when resizing svg-shape

Tags: html, svg, viewbox

I have a svg-pattern applied to a polygon. It's working fine. 
When I set another size on the svg-polygon, I don't want to scale the pattern.

I've tried all combinations I can think of with viewBox, patternUnits and patternContentUnits. The goal is to make the polygon work responsibly e.g. scale with it's parent element. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```html
<svg width="1000" fill="#ccc" viewBox="0 0 1440 60">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="900" height="600" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <svg x="0" y="0" width="900.4" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900.4 600">
      <!-- pattern code -->
      </svg>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <polygon points="0,0 1440,0 1440,20 0,60" x="0" y="0" stroke="#bbb" fill="url(#pattern)" />
</svg>

<svg width="500" fill="#ccc" viewBox="0 0 1440 60">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="900" height="600" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <svg x="0" y="0" width="900.4" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900.4 600">
      <!-- pattern code -->
      </svg>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <polygon points="0,0 1440,0 1440,20 0,60" x="0" y="0" stroke="#bbb" fill="url(#pattern)" />
</svg>
```

full example: https://codepen.io/anderssonola/pen/QqxKjJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved temporarily by applying the pattern to a `<rect>`and then use css `clip-path`to create the polygon and the pattern does not scale. I still would prefer to solve it with pure svg, since IE does not support the css `clip-path`.

```css
.clip {
  background: gray;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 0% 100%);
  margin-bottom: 1em; 
}

.clip.half {
  width: 50%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div > 
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="900" height="600" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <svg x="0" y="0" width="900.4" height="600"  >
        <!-- pattern code -->
        </svg>
      </pattern>
      <rect width="100%" height="50" fill="url(#pattern)" id="pattern-md"/>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="clip">
  <svg>
     <use href="#pattern-md"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="clip half" >
  <svg>
     <use href="#pattern-md" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anderssonola/pen/oGyBMj/

Answer (score 1):

You could always scale the pattern and size the polygon appropriately e.g.

```
<polygon transform="scale(2)" points="0,0 720,0 720,10 0,30" stroke="#bbb" fill="url(#pattern)" />
```

Comment: Yeah that works, however I want the polygon to work in a responsive implementation, so a more "generic" approach would be more appropriate. Edited my question to state that.

Comment: You'd have to inverse scale the pattern dynamically on resize then.